# Powershell Array -> HTML as string not as .Length

Tags: arrays, powershell

Currently I have a script that does a bunch of things, one thing is that it checks a .txt file to get all the current servers and then just does a ping to check connectivity before it does the rest of the script. I currently have that setup to add the servers it could not ping into an array so that it will not slow down the rest of the process attempting on failed servers. At the end of the script I have it all converted to an HTML document for ease of viewing. I would like to add the servers that failed the connection to the end of the HTML document to show that those servers failed.

As the script is now, it just prints the .Length property of the array I put those servers in. Here is the code I have that sets up the array, adds servers to it, and then the convertto-html part.

```
$servers = Get-Content "path\to\text.txt"
$failedConn = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]'

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
     $pingResult = Get-Ciminstance -ClassName win32_pingstatus -Filter "address='$server' and timeout=1000"
     if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) 
     {
         Write-Host "$server ping successful
     }
     else
     {
         Write-Host "$server ping Fail" -ForegroundColor Red
         $failedConn.Add($server)
         <# Also tried $failedConn += ($server) with the same error #>
     }
}
<# Code for a forloop to do tasks where it adds an HTML variable called CombinedBody styling the tables whatnot #>
$CombinedBody += $failedConn | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -Append C:\Path\To\html.html
```

The result just puts the failed connections at the very bottom of the HTML document, but it prints it as the length of each server name. How do I get it to print the actual server name? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to provide functional code (even if it errors) that will reproduce the issue. You never even add anything to `$failedConn` in your code here.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician My apologies. I forgot to add that line. I'll edit now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Length` is the only property in the `String` object that `ConvertTo-Html` sees so that's what gets output. As a workaround, you can wrap the server names in another object that only have a single property containing the name, then it should output the actual names. Like this:

```
$failedConn | foreach{[pscustomobject]@{"Failed Servers" = $_}} | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -Append C:\Path\To\html.html
```

Note that I've removed  `$CombinedBody +=`  since `Out-File` doesn't return any output so that won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks!

As for wrapping the names in another object, how would I do that one?

Comment: @Angziety see my example in my answer. This part `foreach{[pscustomobject]@{"Failed Servers" = $_}}`

Comment: I assume you want me to add another object in place of pscumstomobject? I tried what you had and it just printed another number this time a number that kinda made no sense haha. I have a test.txt file right now with 3 servers that are bound to fail, all with 11 characters in the name. With the few things I've tried, I've gotten 11 printed 3 times, or a 33. This time it printed 84.

Comment: No the `pscustomobject` *is* the wrapper object. Take out the `ConvertTo-Html` to see what object is generated.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I just tried it, the out-file printed Failed Servers ------------ server1 server2 server3

Comment: Hmm, seems like it should be working then. Not sure why it's not working for you. I updated the answer to suggest adding the `-Property` switch to the convert command to try and convince it to do the right thing/

Comment: Gave the code a day and re-ran it. It for whatever reason works now. with the given answer. I work in an environment where GPOs change daily and it does sometimes affect our powershell scripts. I'm just going to chock it up to magic.

However, it does work now, so I really appreciate your time and effort! Thank you so much!!